# Grunt / Babel error: Unable to write "dist" file (Error code: EISDIR)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-babel

I am new to Grunt and all its plugins, but I want to learn and setup some awesome front-end tools. With that said, I have been following the [Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks) and some's similar issue with Grunt and Babel via [Github](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel/issues/31), but I seem to keep getting the following traceback:

```
Running "babel:dist" (babel) task
Warning: Unable to write "dist" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any clearer explanation to this newbie would be HIGHLY appreciated. I'm new to programming in JS and setting up DevOps, so some helpful tips and best practices are encouraged.

---

Setup:

js_practice/ (Root Project) 
|----package.json

All the distributions and packages
|---node_modules/

Server-Side (Node) support
|---es6/
| ------ test.js 
|---dist/

Client (browser) support
|----public/
|---es6/ (this is within the public folder) 
| ----- test2.js 
|---dist/ (this is within the public folder)

Here is my current code:

**Grunt file.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
        // All of your Grunt code must be specified inside this function!
        // Setup configuration...
    // Load tasks...
    // Define tasks...

    grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            babel: {
                     options: {
                             sourceMap: true,
                             presets: ['babel-preset-es2015']
                     },
                     dist: {
                             files: [
                                 // Node source
                                 {
                                 src: ['es6/**/*.js'],
                                 dest: 'dist'},
                                 // Browser source
                                {
                                    src: ['public/es6/**/*.js'],
                                    dest: 'public/dist'},
                        ],
                    },
             },

            browserify: {
           dist: {
             options: {
               transform: [["babelify", { "stage": 0 }]]
             },
             files: {
               "build/bundle.js": "src/main.js"
             }
           }
             },

        jshint: {
            scripts: {
                src: ['scripts/**.js', 'lib/**.js']
            },

            tests: { // We can have more than one jshint task, this ones called `jshint:tests`
                src: 'tests/**.js'
            }
        },

                uglify: {
              options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
              },
              build: {
                src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
                dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
              },
            scripts: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'scripts/',
                src: '**.js',
                dest: 'build/',
                ext: '.min.js'
            }
        },

        watch: {
                    scripts: {
                    files: ['**/*.js'],
                    tasks: ['jshint'],
                        },

            styles: {
                files: 'styles/**.less',
                task: 'less:styles'
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel','browserify','jshint']);
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['jshint', 'uglify']);

};
```

Comment: This is nodejs' way of saying "Hey, you're trying to write a file called dist, but there is already a directory called dist in this location." Anyway, since you already have `transform: [["babelify", { "stage": 0 }]]` in the browserify task, do you need the babel task? Also, jshint could preferably be run before the other tasks, and while we're at it, there's usually no need to do jshint on you lib files.

Comment: @dannyjolie I'm new to this and read through so many recommendations. Should I just use browserfiy task instead of babel? I can move jshint above all the rest. Mind cleaning it up as an answer with the notes? Of why I should or shouldn't have on plugin over the other? thanks!!

Comment: On second thought, having both babel and browserify with babelify makes sense if you cater for both server and browser applications. I haven't used Grunt in quite a while, so I can't just write a gruntfile off the top of my head that I know will work, but I'll try to write up an answer :)

Comment: thanks @dannyjolie :) do you use Gulp instead? I wasn't sure which one I should start with or is better, just took a leap.

Comment: Currently I use Gulp, yes, but I don't call favorites. And then there's always Brunch and Broccolli and a ton of other task runners. I believe the hipsters have moved on to just using npm scripts, skipping task runners altogether, but sometimes you just want to pick a tool, say "hey, this works for me", and stick with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just expanding on what I said in the comments

> Any clearer explanation to this newbie would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Nodejs is trying to write a file called `dist`, but produces an error because a directory with this name exists.

The cause of this is found in the babel task.

```
  files: [{
      src: ['es6/**/*.js'],
      dest: 'dist'
    },
    // Browser source
    {
      src: ['public/es6/**/*.js'],
      dest: 'public/dist'
    }]
```

You have to tell Babel to take each file in `es6/`, transform them and place the new files in the `dist/` folder. As it stand now, the transformer tries to create a file called dist. Rewriting it to

```
  files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'es6/'
      src: ['**/*.js'],
      dest: 'dist/'
    },
    // Browser source
    {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'public/es6/'
      src: ['**/*.js'],
      dest: 'public/dist/'
    }]
```

should yield a better result, but play around with it. Like I mentioned, I haven't used Grunt in a while. [Take a look at the documentation on building the files object](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

And like I said in the comments, use jshint or other such tools (eslint is all the hype...) to keep your own code neat. Don't waste time by running a jshint task on lib files that you probably don't want to fix yourself anyway. And always run jshint on the source files, not files that are transformed by babel or browserify. It's just a tool to help *you* write better code, not some generator.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you. I'll take a look at `eslint` would recommend using it over/instead of `jshint`??

Comment: Well, it's *very* flexible, but it's based on plugins and doesn't really do much out of the box. The recent v2.0.0 had some braking changes that caught me by surprise, but I guess the documentation for eslint should be up to date by now.